# How can I pass hidden values through an ajax call using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-docs

I have a form that uses google docs and when you submit it will go to googles default thank you page. What I want to do is use ajax instead to send the data so the user won't leave the site. Google requires certain hidden fields for their end. How can I pass hidden fields in ajax? Below is the code I wrote.

```
                   $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?formkey=HEREISWHEREMYKEYGOES",
                        data: "name=entry.1.group&value=24",
                        success: function() {
                            alert("yay")
                        },
                        error: function(e) {
                            console.log(e);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Just as regular fields, append them to the data string: "field1=value1&field2=value2" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add fields to a `string` in javascript, you can use below code. Make sure to replace `Whateverfield` to the actual field, but I would need to see the HTML to provide a full answer.

```
formKey = $('Whateverfield').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse",
    data: "name=entry.1.group&value=24&formkey=" + formKey,
    success: function() {
        alert("yay")
    },
    error: function(e) {
         console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Ideally, you use something like this for the data:

```
data: { 
   name: "entry.1.group",
   value: "24", 
   formKey: $('Whateverfield').val()
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass its value through data parameter as in code below:

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?formkey=HEREISWHEREMYKEYGOES",
                        data:  { name="entry.1.group", value= "24", hidden1 = $('#hidden_id').val(), hidden2 = $('#hidden_id2').val() },
                        success: function() {
                            alert("yay")
                        },
                        error: function(e) {
                            console.log(e);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Just pass the hidden fields in the data parameter.  e.g.

```
..
data: {
  ..
  hiddenField1: "hiddenValue1",
  hiddenField2: "hiddenValue2",
  ..
}
```